# How to target different modal on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 3 modals that I am trying to target on click but it keeps opening the same one. Im not to sure how to target each modal individually to get the right one opening on click. This is what I have so far. Am I right in thinking that I would need to give each modal its own unique ID and then target that through jquery instead of just targeting the main .modal class Im currently using.

Thanks

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
  $('.modal').fadeIn();
});

$('.close-btn').click(function() {
  $('.modal').fadeOut();
});
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 5;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 15% auto;
  padding: 40px 40px 0 40px;
  border: 1px solid #efefef;
  width: 50%;
}

.modal-header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #efefef;
}

.modal-body {
  padding: 20px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #efefef;
}

.modal-footer {
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.close-btn {
  width: 150px;
  float: right;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.btn {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 80%;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  background: #F0B67F;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn">Modal 1</div>
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4>Modal 1</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>modal 1.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer clearfix">
      <div class="btn close-btn">CLOSE</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="btn">Modal 2</div>
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4>Modal 2</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>modal 2.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer clearfix">
      <div class="btn close-btn">CLOSE</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="btn">Modal 3</div>
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4>Modal 3</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>modal 3.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer clearfix">
      <div class="btn close-btn">CLOSE</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What you're thinking is probably right. You do need to give unique ID or class to each modal.

Comment: Yes give each one it's own unique ID so you can target them individually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `.modal` matches every element with the class `modal`. You need to change your button's click handler function to only target the one modal element you want to fade in.

My code below shows one approach that would work - it targets the element immediately following the button, using the `next()` function.

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
  $(this).next().fadeIn();
});

$('.close-btn').click(function() {
  $(this).next().fadeOut();
});
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 5;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 15% auto;
  padding: 40px 40px 0 40px;
  border: 1px solid #efefef;
  width: 50%;
}

.modal-header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #efefef;
}

.modal-body {
  padding: 20px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #efefef;
}

.modal-footer {
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.close-btn {
  width: 150px;
  float: right;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.btn {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 80%;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  background: #F0B67F;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn">Modal 1</div>
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4>Modal 1</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>modal 1.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer clearfix">
      <div class="btn close-btn">CLOSE</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="btn">Modal 2</div>
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4>Modal 2</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>modal 2.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer clearfix">
      <div class="btn close-btn">CLOSE</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="btn">Modal 3</div>
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4>Modal 3</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>modal 3.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer clearfix">
      <div class="btn close-btn">CLOSE</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent just what im looking for thanks so much really appreciate your help

Answer (score 2):

Another approach would be to place each modal inside a div, then use `this` keyword to find it's parent, then look for `modal` and fade it.

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().find('.modal').fadeIn();
});

$('.close-btn').click(function() {
  $('.modal').fadeOut();
});
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 5;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 15% auto;
  padding: 40px 40px 0 40px;
  border: 1px solid #efefef;
  width: 50%;
}

.modal-header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #efefef;
}

.modal-body {
  padding: 20px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #efefef;
}

.modal-footer {
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.close-btn {
  width: 150px;
  float: right;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.btn {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 80%;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  background: #F0B67F;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<div class="btn">Modal 1</div>
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4>Modal 1</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>modal 1.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer clearfix">
      <div class="btn close-btn">CLOSE</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div>
<div class="btn">Modal 2</div>
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4>Modal 2</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>modal 2.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer clearfix">
      <div class="btn close-btn">CLOSE</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div>
<div class="btn">Modal 3</div>
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4>Modal 3</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>modal 3.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer clearfix">
      <div class="btn close-btn">CLOSE</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```